# Ruby - XML to Hash and then Hash to XML, both XMLs are not same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, hash

I have an XML like:

```
<response xmlns:msg="http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/messaging/" xmlns:ld="http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/lab-data/">
  <msg:trb proRefId="12345" tesComNa="Xyz Laboratories,Inc.">
    <sample ttz="020206b01" id="1898-57" name="Adam, Franklin" />
  </msg:trb>
</response>
```

I'm supposed to read the XML in ruby and show it in a much readable HASH format in the UI(inside a textarea), where user can edit the values inside the HASH.

Then I'm supposed to form back the XML from the hash.

**But, the initial and final XMLs differ**

**Code**

**XML > HASH**

```
h = Hash.from_xml('
  <response xmlns:msg="http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/messaging/" xmlns:ld="http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/lab-data/">
    <msg:trb proRefId="12345" tesComNa="Xyz Laboratories,Inc.">
      <sample ttz="020206b01" id="1898-57" name="Adam, Franklin" />
    </msg:trb>
  </response>
')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
#{
#  "response" => {
#    "xmlns:msg"=>"http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/messaging/",
#    "xmlns:ld"=>"http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/lab-data/",
#    "trb" => {
#      "proRefId" => "12345",
#      "tesComNa" => "Xyz Laboratories,Inc.",
#      "sample" => {
#        "ttz" => "020206b01",
#        "id" => "1898-57",
#        "name" => "Adam, Franklin"
#      }
#    }
#  }
#}
```

Say user modifies the above and I'm trying to convert the modified HASH to XML again:

**HASH > XML**

```
h["response"].to_xml(root: "response")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<response>
  <xmlns:msg>
    http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/messaging/
  </xmlns:msg>
  <xmlns:ld>
    http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/lab-data/undefined
  </undefinedxmlns:ld>
    undefined
  <trb>
    <proRefId>12345</proRefId>    
    <tesComNa>Xyz Laboratories,Inc.</tesComNa>    
    <sample>      
      <ttz>020206b01</ttz>      
      <id>1898-57</id>      
      <name>Adam, Franklin</name>    
  </sample>
    undefined
    </trb>
  undefined
</response>
```

I see lots of `undefined` and the attributes of any node is converted to node itself.

How can I achieve the original XML back with only it's respective value modified(as done by user)?

Comment: yes, I don't see an easy way here, because hashes can't have attributes on keys. That's why xml->hash transformation makes them separate key-value pairs, which, in turn, correctly become standalone tags.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Also, another problem is, if any tag has a text, eg: `<sample ttz="020206b01" id="1898-57" name="Adam, Franklin">Some Text</sample>`, then converting into HASH would skip the attributes

Comment: It's a general problem: transformations of data from one data model A to another model B are not reversible unless the two data models are isomorphic. Either there will be two values in A that have the same representation in B, or there will be two values in B that have the same representation in A. Your problem is mathematically insoluble.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be related to your environment. I have tested your code with Rails console (Rails 5.1.4) and it works as expected:

```
[1] pry(main)> h = Hash.from_xml('
[1] pry(main)*   <response xmlns:msg="http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/messaging/" xmlns:ld="http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/lab-data/">
[1] pry(main)*     <msg:trb proRefId="12345" tesComNa="Xyz Laboratories,Inc.">
[1] pry(main)*       <sample ttz="020206b01" id="1898-57" name="Adam, Franklin" />
[1] pry(main)*     </msg:trb>
[1] pry(main)*   </response>
[1] pry(main)* ')
=> {"response"=>
  {"xmlns:msg"=>"http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/messaging/",
   "xmlns:ld"=>"http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/lab-data/",
   "trb"=>
    {"proRefId"=>"12345",
     "tesComNa"=>"Xyz Laboratories,Inc.",
     "sample"=>{"ttz"=>"020206b01", "id"=>"1898-57", "name"=>"Adam, Franklin"}}}}

[2] pry(main)> h['response']['trb']['tesComNa'] = 'StackOverflow'
=> "StackOverflow"

[3] pry(main)> puts h["response"].to_xml(root: "response")
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <xmlns:msg>http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/messaging/</xmlns:msg>
  <xmlns:ld>http://schemas.xyzlabs.net/2010/lab-data/</xmlns:ld>
  <trb>
    <proRefId>12345</proRefId>
    <tesComNa>StackOverflow</tesComNa>
    <sample>
      <ttz>020206b01</ttz>
      <id>1898-57</id>
      <name>Adam, Franklin</name>
    </sample>
  </trb>
</response>
```

Comment: No, it's not as expected. `xmlns:msg` is now its own tag, but it should be an attribute.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. You can clearly see that the XMLs are different. Eg:- `xmlns:msg` is not supposed to be an individual tag. It's supposed to be an attribute of `response`

Comment: Now I got your point. I thought that the main problem is `undefined`. In this case, I think that the easiest solution will be to use gem for parsing XML (for instance Nokogiri).

Comment: I do use Nokogiri. But, I'm unsure how to achieve the above scenario with it